# Bash. Using ccze without altering data for parsing

Tags: bash, parsing, stdout, tee, colorize

I have a complex command on my bash script which prints a lot of info on stdout. This command is complex and takes some time to finish but is fully working. At the same time, I'm using a pipe with tee to write it into a file for a post-parsing task.

```
cmd="myComplexCommand | tee /dev/fd/5"
exec 5>&1
stored_output=$(eval "${cmd}")
```

Until here everything is working.

Now, I'm trying to implement ccze to colorize screen output. Usually to use it on any command is as simple as:

```
anyCommand | ccze -A
```

And everything is printed in a beauty colorized way. The problem is if I try to apply this to my particular case, after using the pipe to ccze on my myComplexCommand, the output on screen is colorized (nice!) but it alters the output stored on the file I want to parse on my post-parse task and it doesn't work.

Is there a Bash way to print a command using ccze in a beauty way on screen and at the same time store it in a file (without ccze modifications) to parse it later?

Comment: BTW, using `eval` is a serious code smell here. Much better practice to use a function to store code: `cmd() { myComplexCommand | tee /dev/fd/5; }`, and then just invoke `cmd`.

Answer (score 1):

`tee` to file at a point in the pipeline *before* the colorization takes place:

```
myComplexCommand | tee filename | ccze -A
```

---

Incidentally, with bash 4.1 or later, if you want to send a *lot* of data both to a file and in colorized form to the TTY, you might put both those operations in a single process substitution:

```
exec {stdout_backup}>&1
exec {store_and_colorize}> >(tee filename | ccze -A | tee /dev/fd/"$stdout_backup")
```

and then reuse that process substitution as many times as you like:

```
result=$(something >&$store_and_colorize)
another_result=$(something_else >&$store_and_colorize)
```

That way you've got exactly one copy of `ccze` persisting across multiple uses.

Comment: Have you got any documentation on that  proc sub usage? Never seen it before.

Comment: Which details are unfamiliar? The `exec {name}> ...` is bash 4.1's automatic FD allocation, not specific to process substitution.

Comment: Yep that, I wouldn't know what it's specific to. Nvm `automatic FD allocation` was enough to find it, cheers.